# How to intercept the changes to this properties window?

Tags: visual-studio, events, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm trying to intercept the change events triggered (any field) when this property window is changed in a VS Extension project (vsix). This extension will target VS versions upto 2019 (the latest one).

I've used `dte.Events.TextEditorEvents.LineChanged` but it captures the event intermittently.

Is there a specific event that I can look at for this purpose?

[image]

Comment: Did you want to detect the Application arguments  textbox or the whole Debug Properties Window? Any more detailed info will be expected..

Comment: That particular designer (aka the project designer), isn't the text editor, so I'm not sure how TextEditorEvents.LineChanged would ever come into play here. Which field or property are you looking to receive a change notification for? I'm not sure there is a change notification for any of these, aside from the project file being dirtied, because you change one or more of the project settings (as indicated by the asterisk)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT It can be any field in any of the tabbed window be it Debug or Build or Application.

Comment: @EdDore Same as above. Any event that points to the window values being changed should suffice. It's not only Debug window. If values change in other tabs then the event raised should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I mistakenly thought [IVsRunningDocTableEvents.OnAfterAttributeChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdoctableevents.onafterattributechange) could be used. But after reviewing the designer code base (one of the few I've seen written in VB.NET), I found that this particular designer sets the windowframe's dirty by explicitly invoking IVsWindowFrame.SetProperty with [VSFPROPID_OverrideDirtyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vsfpropid2), which per the comments in the vsshell80.idl file:

```
VSFPROPID_OverrideDirtyState  = -4014,  // BOOL/EMPTY -- tri-state value to control dirty star (*) in window caption 
//      VT_EMPTY: default handling of dirty star
//      VARIANT_TRUE: override default handling to SHOW dirty star
//      VARIANT_FALSE: override default handling to show NO dirty star
```

indicates this designer doesn't leverage the default mechanism driven by the RDT. :-(

The only notification I could find that you could possibly intercept would be an IPropertyNotifyChange on the individual properties themselves, which does fire, as soon as you change a given setting and move focus to another control.

This may not be what you're looking for, but if you can explain why you need such a notification, I may be able to come up with something better than periodically polling the designers VSFPROPID_OverrideDirtyState property (which is the only other thing that immediately comes to mind).

Thanks,
Ed....

Comment: The reason why I'm looking to intercept this change event is to trigger a save on the project settings/properties when it's been changed. This is an extension which I'm trying to add this functionality to - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HangjitRai.AutoSaveFile

Comment: do you think you can help?

Comment: If you are looking to auto-save after x number of seconds, then you don't really need to do anything other than issue a Save All command every x number of seconds, by calling something like IVsUIShell.PostExecCommand.

Comment: I only want to trigger that `x` seconds after the LAST change. @EdDore